# Simple_form association helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a Product model and a Size model. I want to display a drop down in my simple form of the sizes available for each product. I think i need to use the association helper provided by simple_form but i cannot get it to work. Can anyone help? Thanks

The error i get is:

`Association cannot be used in forms not associated with an object`

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :order_products
    has_many :orders, through: :order_products
    has_many :sizes

end
```

**Size.rb**

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :product

end
```

**products/show.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for :basket, url: product_basket_path(@product), remote: true do |f| %>

<%= f.input :quantity, as: :select, collection: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], selected: 1, required: false %>

<%= f.association :size %>


<%= f.button :submit, "Add to basket" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
<%= f.input :size, as: :select, collection: @product.sizes."row_name", required: false %>
```

Comment: great, thanks, only problem is that it displays the hash rather than the actual human-readable size?

Comment: @James, i have no idea about your sizes model. Share it. could be product.sizes.size

Comment: Thanks man, i've just added this to my Size model `def to_s "#{size}"
end`

Comment: @James Great, you can accept it a working answer so save the next person from hustle.